# Why does zlib.decompressobj succeed but zlib.decompress fail?

Tags: python

I thought these implementations are effectively the same. Why does one succeed but the other fail?

```py
import zlib

data = b'x\x9c4\xc9A\x0e\x820\x10\x05\xd0\xbb\xfcuk\x8a\xe8f\xaeB\t\x19`\x82MJ!\xed\xa81M\xef\xae\x1bw/y\x15\nJ\xcf\x18\r\xca\x1f\xc7\t\xea\x9c\xc1\n\xaax\x08g\x9d\x85u\nI%\xbf8\x82n\xdd\xf5\xfe\xfbI3/\x02\x1a0xl\xac\xf2\xe6\x8f=\xf3jw\x0e\xc9\xf6E7\x0fS=\xf6\xb0\xe4\xa3x\x90\xbb\xb86bl\xed\x0b\x00\x00\xff\xff'

result = zlib.decompressobj().decompress(data)
print(result)

result2 = zlib.decompress(data)
print(result2)
```

Result:

```
b'{"t":null,"s":null,"op":10,"d":{"heartbeat_interval":41250,"_trace":["[\\"gateway-prd-main-3stg\\",{\\"micros\\":0.0}]"]}}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    result2 = zlib.decompress(data)
zlib.error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream
```

Comment: The `decompressobj` is fine with a partial stream; it does as much as it can, and assumes you will give it more data later, and call `flush()` at the end. `zlib.decompress()` assumes you have given it a complete stream of compressed data and fails if you don't.

Comment: The stream *is* incomplete; you could determine this by looking at the `.eof` attribute of the decompression object after you had called `.decompress(data)` on it.  No error is generated in the first case, because the process was never finalized; you could very well have called `.decompress()` again with additional data.  I suspect that whatever code created this compressed data simply failed to call `.flush()` on the compression object (or the equivalent in whatever language was used to implement it).

Comment: The problem seems to be that there's extra data at the end. When you use the decompress object, you just get the first completed block. When you use `zlib.decompress()` it tries to decompress everything, and gets an error from the incomplete second block.